# Apache Camel download progress

Tags: scala, apache-camel, akka

I am using Apache Camel to download FTP files.

Is there a way to get the download progress?  The headers expose the total file size, but I don't have any access to the download byte stream, as far as I can find.  If I did, I could manually tally up the bytes, and divide that by the total to get a percentage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with Camel out of the box as the default file component does not expose this level of detail. However I believe you can extend the existing FTP component to do what you want relatively easily.

I am assuming that you have a flow which is triggered by an FTP source. The Apache Camel FTP component (part of "[File2](https://camel.apache.org/file2.html)") only emits an event once the file has been fully downloaded. The FTP component uses the Apache Commons FTP client (see [FtpOperations.java](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-ftp/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/remote/FtpOperations.java)). I would start by creating my own FTP component derived from Camel's which adds a way to supply a Camel endpoint to be notified periodically of progress using this approach [described elsewhere on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875837/monitoring-progress-using-apache-commons-ftpclient). Your new component could take an additional parameter which will tell it where to send in-progress notifications, e.g.:

```
<from uri="ftp://remote.site/directory/*.csv?progressNotifications=seda:ftp-progress-messages"/>
```

You can define your own message format and have the FtpOperations and friends emit any event into that channel that you may be interested in -- e.g. download start, progress events at certain frequency / milestones, download end, download error, etc.

The overall "FTP" source component is defined in [FtpComponent.java](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-ftp/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/remote/FtpComponent.java). This is responsible for orchestrating all the other pieces based on a Camel URI for a given FTP source (or destination, as the case may be).

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful and gives me something to start with.